# Share Extension not appearing in the list of apps on capable of Sharing Photo on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to create a share app extension and followed the tutorial from this source:

```
http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/share-extension-in-ios-application-overview-with-example/
```

I am using XCode 8.0 (8A218a) On simulator it works as expected. On my iPhone 5s with iOS 9.3.3.

I install the container application first and then run Extension by choosing Photos app when XCode asks "Choose an app to run".

Now when I open a photo while extension is running, the following error appears:

```
MobileSlideShow[3500:589624] *** error reading settings archive file: <ISRootSettings:
/var/mobile/Documents/com.apple.mobileslideshow.settings/ISRootSettings_10.plist>
```

Now when I tap the Share button, my container app doesn't appear in the list of Apps capable of Sharing picture.

**EDIT:**
I am sharing some code:

**ShareViewController.m**

```
@implementation ShareViewController
- (BOOL)isContentValid {
    // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
    return YES;
}

- (void)didSelectPost {

    for (NSItemProvider* itemProvider in ((NSExtensionItem*)self.extensionContext.inputItems[0]).attachments ) {

        if([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.jpeg"]) {
            NSLog(@"itemprovider = %@", itemProvider);

            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.jpeg" options:nil completionHandler: ^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error) {

                NSData *imgData;
                if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
                    imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)item];
                }
                if([(NSObject*)item isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) {
                    imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage*)item);
                }

                NSDictionary *dict = @{
                                       @"imgData" : imgData,
                                       @"name" : self.contentText
                                       };
                NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.iosApp.testSharing"];
                [defaults setObject:dict forKey:@"img"];
                [defaults synchronize];
            }];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.iosApp.testSharing"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [defaults valueForKey:@"img"];

    if (dict) {

         NSData *imgData = [dict valueForKey:@"imgData"];
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
         [_shareImageView setImage:image];
         _shareImageNameLabel.text = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
         [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"img"];
     }

 }

@end
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to change the deployment target of share extension form target of your project then it starts working.

Comment: The language wasn't clear to me at first here, but as other answers have noted, I had to change the deployment target in Build Settings for the extension to match the main target's deployment target. When you create a new extension in xcode, it automatically sets the deployment target to the latest OS version instead of matching the main target's deployment target version

Answer (score 15):

Your testing iPhone version is lower than your `Deployment Info` setting:

[image: e]

Comment: @famfamfam Xcode 15 try `Minimum Deployments`

Comment: This also just fixed it for me in Jan 2024, thank you!!

Answer (score 10):

For me unchecking the **Copy only when installing** option worked.
This option can be found under Build Phases > Embed App Extensions.

Answer (score 5):

You have to make sure what kind extension identifier you need `com.apple.ui-services` or `com.apple.share-services`

that's my configuration example:

[image: ui services]

This is where it appears using ui-services:

[image]

And here using the `com.apple.share-services` :

[image]

and then:

[image]

And for everything works fine, don't forget to make sure that your project has the same deployment info target version that your target (General/Deployment Info/Deployment Target)

see ya, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I went through the *technetexperts* tutorial, a probable issue looks like the `@"group.iosApp.testSharing"` passed to `NSUserDefaults` doesn't matches the one described in `.plist`

Comment: Thanks, but plist doesn't have to have this app group name.
The problem was actually something else. This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42273617/5237727.

By default the deployment target of the Share extension was iOS 10.0