# Share extension does not appear in capable apps if NSExtensionActivationRule is set for audio only

Tags: ios, share-extension

I am trying to create a share extension where the users can upload her audio recordings from any capable app. The documentation even has a straightforward example (see [Declaring Supported Data Types for a Share or Action Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8)) (also brought up in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29546283/ios-share-extension-how-to-support-wav-files)), but it does not work in any audio recorder (on iOS 10.3.3, iPad).

Looking at the [Uniform Type Identifiers Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html), I need `public.audio`. The relevant entry in the share extension's `Info.plist`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

To narrow it down, I tried changing `NSExtensionActivationRule` to `public.mpeg4` and `public.audiovisual-content`, same results.

When I change the `NSExtensionActivationRule` to conform to `public.image` though, it shows up in photo apps:

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
).@count == 1
```

Changing `NSExtensionActivationRule` to `TRUEPREDICATE` string would make it to finally show up in audio apps as well, but of course, this wouldn't be accepted in the App Store.

I also tried every above step on a clean start (i.e., clean + clean build folder + delete DerivedData contents + remove app from iPad), but the results where the same.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269842/share-extension-not-appearing-in-the-list-of-apps-on-capable-of-sharing-photo-on) also seemed relevant, but changing the share extension's deployment target didn't help.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE: As Jamshed Alam states in his comment, **changes in iOS 13 make this answer obsolete**.

My share extension would allow uploading audio files to a Firebase backend, and I naively assumed that audio recording apps would appropriately declare their supported file types, but they don't. Most conform to multiple uniform type identifiers (see [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)) with `public.data` being the most common.

I found [this Github issue from 2014](https://github.com/tumblr/ios-extension-issues/issues/5) and used it as a reference. Its title perfectly summarizes the problem:

> Share extensions will *only* show up if they explicitly support *all*
>   of the provided activity items

The solution of using [`NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW36) worked for me too. According to [Information Property Key List Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html):

> **Activation dictionary version 1** Only when the app extension handles
>   ***all*** of the asset types being offered by a host app item provider
>
> **Activation dictionary version 2** When the app extension handles ***at
>   least one*** of the asset types being offered by a host app item provider

My share extension's `Info.plist` looks like this now:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMinCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>20</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

Or in Xcode:

[image]

Using only `NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount` besides `NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion` would probably have sufficed.

Comment: Did you test it for iOS 13 ? Not working share extension anymore, apple removed openURL:..() method for share extension completely.

Comment: Thanks for the update! For the record, haven't touched iOS stuff since last Spring...

Comment: Please test and let me know if there any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `public.mpeg-4-audio` helps show app in sharesheet where it previously won't show for `public.audio`. It might be unfeasible to do this for each and every extension type. But the list of extensions can be found at [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://www.escapetech.eu/manuals/qdrop/uti.html) under `Audiovisual content types`.

The best case scenerio seems to be structuring the query like this. I have included some famous extensions, but there are others in the link above.

```
SUBQUERY(
    $extensionItem.attachments, 
    $attachment, 
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.audio" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.mpeg-4-audio" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.mp3" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.windows-media-wma" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.aifc-audio" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.aiff-audio" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.midi-audio" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.ac3-audio" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.waveform-audio" ||
    ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.OTHER_EXTENSIONS" ||
).@count = 1
```